# Gstreamer audio problem on embedded linux

Tags: audio, embedded-linux, gstreamer, hardware-acceleration, mpeg

I work on embedded linux. I want play video with minimum CPU. So after I completed compile, I tried play video with mplayer  and gstreamer. Mplayer use CPU avarage %10-20. I want to obtain this perform on gstreamer. So I tried these command:

1- `gst-launch filesrc location=video_path.mpeg ! mpegdemux ! mpeg2dec ! autovideosink`

2-`gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=video_path.mpeg ! dvddemux ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! xvimagesink`

These commands use avarage %10-20 CPU. This number that I want number. But audio did not work with these command. I tried added audio element but I could not achieve.

I also tried `gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///video_path.mpeg`. Audio work with this command but CPU usage is so high and I don2t prefer this.

How can I work audio with 1 or 2 commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- gst-launch filesrc location=video_path.mpeg ! mpegdemux ! mpeg2dec
>   ! autovideosink
>
> 2-gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=video_path.mpeg ! dvddemux !
>   mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! xvimagesink

With the above two pipelines you are asking gtreamer to just play video, as a result you aren’t getting any audio.

> gst-launch filesrc location=video_path.mpeg ! mpegdemux name=demuxer
>   demuxer. ! queue ! mpeg2dec ! autovideosink demuxer. ! queue ! mad ! 
>   audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink

The above pipeline should play both audio and video.

Note: If you have support for hardware decoding that would reduce further CPU usage.

Comment: In addition, GstElement should use this shape: `mpegdemux name=demuxer demuxer.video_00` and `autovideosink demuxer.audio_00`. Otherwise, you can see warning:`pipeline: could not link queue0 to mpeg2dec0`

Comment: How can I do same process with `fbdevsink`? Can you help with this? Thank you so much.